# Как проверить возраст с помощью moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Как проверить возраст с помощью *moment.js*, чтобы было от 14 до 100 лет?

Пробовал так, `value` приходит как `'01.02.1993'`:

```
if (moment().unix() >= moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ').add(MINAGE, 'y').unix()) {
    isValidAge = true;
}

if (!(isValid && moment().unix() <= moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ').add(MAXAGE, 'y').unix())) {
   isValidAge = false;
}
```

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
let year = moment().diff('1985-03-20', 'years', false);
console.log(year > 14 ? true : false);
```

Comment: то есть нужно приводить значение 01.02.1994 к формате 1994-02-01?

Comment: только тогда работать будет?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function differenceDate(fromDate) {
    const formats = ["DD.MM.YYYY", "DD/MM/YYYY", "DD-MM-YYYY", "DD MM YYYY"];
    const castDate = moment(fromDate, formats);
    return moment().diff(castDate, 'years', false);
}

function checkAgeValid(age) {
    return age > 14 && age < 100;
}

const ages = [
    differenceDate('01.02.1993'),
    differenceDate('01/02/2012'),
    differenceDate('01-02-2005'),
    differenceDate('01 02 1920'),
]

for (const age of ages) console.log(age, checkAgeValid(age));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```